# NODEJS How to block sending socket.emit on web browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKhFA.png)

How to block sending socket.emit on browser ?

```
server

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('singupCheck', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});

Browser console

var socket = io();
socket.emit('singupCheck','test');
```

Comment: Please share your code as text (not image) and be specific at which point you're having trouble.

Comment: Not clear what you asking?

Comment: My problem; Sending socket.emit codes on web browser.

Comment: Is there any error or what is your actual issue?

Comment: I want to stop this.Users should not send socket.emit using the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't block `emit` function on `socket.io` in the console.

But, for example, you can check data on the `Node.js` side and then decide what you need to do.

For example:

```
socket.on('event', (data) => {
    if (!data) {
        throw new Error('Empty data');
    }

    //do something
});
```

For this case you will secure your event for empty data.
Also you can check type of expected data.

Comment: Yes, I cant block emit function on socket.io in the console.How do I know if the incoming request comes from the user or the console? Is there an available parameter for this?

Comment: @YusufCiva
Unfortunately, this parameter is not provided by the library:
https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack